# Saving photo to library more than once using ALAssetsLibrary causes crash

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I have a method that saves a photo to the user's photo library. This code works perfectly the first time you save the photo to the library, but if you try to save it a second time the app will crash.

Here is the method:

```
- (void)saveToLibray
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    // Request to save the image to camera roll
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[self.image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[self.image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

        if (error) {

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Could not save photo to your library. Please enable Halfsies in Settings > Privacy > Photos." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];

            CGImageRelease([self.image CGImage]);

        } else if (!error) {

            UIAlertView *librarySaveSuccessAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Your finished halfsie was successfully saved to your photo library!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [librarySaveSuccessAlertView show];

         CGImageRelease([self.image CGImage]);

        }
    }];
}
```

I have made sure to release the `CGImage` and I am also waiting for the `librarySaveSuccessAlertView` to show on the screen, clicking it's OK button (`cancelButtonTitle`), and then I try and save a second time.

On the second time, the app always crashes.

Is this happening because the library can detect duplicate photos, or is it something else?

EDIT: Crash details

On the line that is highlighted green after the app crashes, it says:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x657471ef)
```

EDIT 2: Ok, so I realize now that it is most likely because I am trying to send a message to a released object. I'm confused on how I should handle this. Even though I'm releasing the `CGImage` data of `self.image`, I should still be able to access it again on the second save correct?

Comment: And what _is_ the crash? These things are usually quite informative, you know. Don't just say "it crashes". What actually happens? It might have nothing to do with the code you just showed...

Comment: can you put the logs of the crash

Comment: Sorry about that I don't have much experience debugging. Please see my edit.

Comment: Please see my second edit.

Comment: Turn on Zombies! This will tell you immediately what object you are attempting to bad-access.

Comment: @matt isn't that pointless seeing as though the only image I'm releasing is the CGImage property of self.image?

Comment: You've already solved the problem, but still, Zombies is a good technique to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already suspect (well done), the problem is this line:

```
CGImageRelease([self.image CGImage])
```

You are required to release a CG-type object if and only if you called a `Create` or `Copy` method to obtain it. For example, you might have obtained this CGImage by calling the function `CGImageCreate()`. You didn't do anything like that here, so this is not your object to release. So simply cut those lines, stop doing incorrect memory management, and all will be well.

Comment: Here's my full discussion of the matter: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_cftyperefs

Comment: It's working perfectly now. Thank you for the help. I'm going to read your article and explore zombies further. Thank you.

Comment: You did all the work! I didn't read your code carefully because you didn't say what the crash was. Once you said what it was and _you_ figured out what this meant, it was obvious what the issue was. You were 9/10 of the way there. Nice detective work.